# how to find out if user input has x characters

Tags: java

trying to make another && to see if the `lock_combination` is exactly 9 characters long

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class charlespeppers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String lock_combination;
        System.out.print ("Please enter a lock combination ( ddRddLddR ) : ");
        lock_combination = user_input.next();


        if (lock_combination.charAt(0) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(0)<= '9' 
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(1) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(1)<= '9'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(3) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(3)<= '9'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(4) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(4)<= '9'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(6) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(6)<= '9'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(7) >= '0' && lock_combination.charAt(7)<= '9'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(2) == 'R'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(8) == 'R'
        &&  lock_combination.charAt(5) == 'L'
        &&  lock_combination == 9);
        {
            System.out.println("This is a valid lock combination.");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: lock_combination.length()?

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions? This tool could make your code much more concise.

Comment: I am aware of some, but now my code will not let me add an else statement after the first system.out.println. It will also print the line I have even if the combination does not match any of the above requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method of `String`:

> **`public int length()`**: Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.

```
if (... && lock_combination.length() == 9)
    System.out.println("This is a valid lock combination.");
```

Comment: Thank you. Another question is how do I go about closing a scanner in this script? I've tried many places by putting Scanner.close(); and it is telling me it "cannot make a static reference to the non static method close() from the type scanner"

Comment: @user3316886 Are you using `Scanner.close()`? You **must** use `user_input.close()`. Read about `static` in Java.

Comment: Oh I see that now because the scanner is "user_input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To find length of lock_combination you can use the following piece of code :

```
if(lock_combination.length() == 9)
```